# Expression Language evaluated in Apache Web Server

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I am having an Apache Web server 2.0 and Tomcat server 7.0.

Web server directs the request to Tomcat server.

Both web and tomcat application servers are directly accessible.

When expression language ${9-4} is sent as a request parameter to web server URL, then the expression is getting evaluated and returning a result of 5.

If the same request is sent to Tomcat server then the result is ${9-4} without evaluation.

Eg:

Web Server

Request: http://apache-web-server:port/context?test=${9-4}

Response when printing test in jsp: 5

Tomcat Server

Request: http://tomcat-server:port/context?test=${9-4}

Response when printing test in jsp: ${9-4}

Is Apache Web server evaluating the expression language here?

How can I stop the server from evaluating the expression language?

Also I am using Struts 2 in the Tomcat Application server.

If the Apache Web server has the capability of evaluating expressions, then how do I turn off OGNL expression evaluation in Apache Web server?

Comment: `Response when printing test in jsp` ain't both examples same! with just heading change ? Is tomcat sitting behind an apache ? Do you mean sending the request directly to tomcat works but through apache doesn't ?

Comment: Yes. In my environment, tomcat server is accessible directly as well as through Apache Web server.

The heading change says that the below request is for Web server or tomcat server.

When I use the Apache web server URL and send test=${9-4} as the request parameter, the expression is being evaluated.

But this is not the case when the same request is sent to Tomcat server directly.

Comment: Could you post and example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JSP Expression Language is parsing your parameter. Its actually a remote code execution vulnerability your application have.

Look at this articles:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Expression_Language_Injection
http://danamodio.com/appsec/research/spring-remote-code-with-expression-language-injection/

Answer (score 0):

Why you pass these are as the values in the url. Instead of that you can pass these vales in the variables and assign access the variables values from jsp or controller then you can write the logic there.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP question.